Azure Function Host Builder Console Errors & Exceptions
I have an Azure Function app with the following code which is called from the program.cs HostBuilder().ConfigureServices:
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config[key]))
{
    var errorMessage = $"Configuration key '{key}' is missing or empty.";
    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage); // this isn't shown on the console ?!
    throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage); // if I remove this, then I see the console message, but I want an exception raised.
}

This checks some basic config settings and shows the next dev what they're missing in their local.settings.json, however the console message does not show up.
What is the best way to inform the user & log in Azure what is missing?
Here's what I've learned so far
Exceptions that occur on startup will not be logged to the console or application insights, so...
On localhost, you can debug and see where exception occurs.
In Azure: Login to the Azure Portal, navigate to the Function App > Diagnose and solve problems

Scroll down, look under Popular troubleshooting tools
Function App Down or Reporting Errors,
Functions that are not tittering > view Details
Look through the list of exceptions (probably near the top)

The above is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62688703/74449
Errors may 'cached' in the portal, see how to clear them here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76232621/74449
Simplified Example
The project targets .NET 8.0 with "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
program.cs:
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var errorMessage = $"Oh no";
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessage); // this isn't shown on the console ?!
        throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);

    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Gives this console log:
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-09-18T03:26:05.944Z] Found C:\Repos\__redacted__\redacted.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 15024) exited with code -1.
Press any key to close this window . . .

If I change throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage) to return then the log shows this:
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-09-18T03:30:06.504Z] Found C:\Repos\__redacted__\redacted.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-09-18T03:30:09.835Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 4448) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-09-18T03:30:09.835Z] Oh no
[2024-09-18T03:30:09.899Z] Worker process started and initialized.
... etc...


Can you please share the error which you got and share the full code which you tried?

What is the dotnet version you are using?

@Pavan Added example

@RithwikBojja .Net 8.0 targeting dotnet-isolated runtime (added to question)

In Isolated Azure Functions, The function starts at Program.cs, If we throw an exception from program.cs it will not log when running in Local or Azure after deployment:

In local, it does not start running after pressing Continue.
But if you want to log that error and run the rest of the function you use can below Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var rith = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((context, rit) =>
    {
        rit.AddLogging();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(ss =>
    {
        ss.AddConsole();
    })
    .Build();
var ricfg = rith.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
var rilg = rith.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
var ri = "xxx";
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ricfg[ri]))
{
    var errorMessage = $"Hello Rithwik,  key '{ri}' is not there";
    rilg.LogError(errorMessage);
}
rith.Run();


So, from the above observations, i came to a conclusion that if any exception thrown from Program.cs don't log in exception nor the function will be available after deploement. Only exceptions coming other than Program.cs will work.

This seems to be no more effective in showing errors on the console than the original code.
It does log the error to app insights (only if I don't throw an exception),
